# Get current display mode

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Assuming the following custom mode provider:

```
DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.Insert(1, new DefaultDisplayMode("CustomMode")
{
ContextCondition = //some bool logic
});
```

How can I get the current display mode from my code?

Comment: What do you mean with "Display Mode"? Screen size?

Comment: @ivowiblo see http://www.sitepoint.com/asp-net-mvc-4-developer-preview-display-modes/

Answer (score -1):

Following the documentation, the current display mode suffix will be the user agent. You could get it from `HttpContext.Current.Request.UserAgent`

In order to get the DisplayMode object, you can do:

```
var currentMode = DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.SingleOrDefault(x => x.DisplayModeId == HttpContext.Current.Request.UserAgent);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: What if the mode is not based on the user agent?

Comment: From the link you've provided: "Basically, Display Modes checks the User Agent.  If it finds a matching suffix, it will display any view it finds that matches the suffix.  The suffix is the parameter that’s passed to the DefaultDisplayMode method."

Comment: display mode is not tied to user agent. That is only one options that can be measured to assign a display mode to a request. Other options are user logon or lack there of, cookies set to save user's preferred display etc.